# One of my table are suddenly gone, how do I trace this?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection, data-loss

So I just noticed one of my table have been dropped/deleted, I am using MySQL anyway I can trace or see logs of this?

I have no idea where to start look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have binary logging enabled, you could probably see the `DROP TABLE` command in the binlog. However, that won't help you get the table back, of course. You would need to restore your data from a backup.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are keeping regular backups.

The next question is, why has this happened? Is your site vulnerable to SQL injection? Building SQL queries/statements with 'literals' from an external source, is inherently vulnerable.

For example: `"select * from CUSTOMER where name='".cust_name."'"`, and all queries/statements like it, are vulnerable to attack.

Calling from the web such that `cust_name=test';drop table CUSTOMER;` supplies the closing apostrophe, issues a semicolon to complete the statement *and then issues malicious commands which will be executed.*

You should use *parameterized queries* and bind parameters explicitly.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection